# SSRS Report;Suppress white space from the report header for the first page

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have an issue in SSRS report page,which is showing blank white space in the each and every page of the report header(I don't want to display header for the first page and should display for the rest of the pages based on the conditions).

Comment: How are you hiding your header on your first page ?

Comment: I am using expressions to hide controls on the header and check print on last page in report header properties.

Comment: You can not supress the whitespace on your first page you should `unckeck` the print on first page. You can not supress because the controls are there it just not visible. That's why it is not possible to supress the header space.

Comment: Yes,It seems no solution for this question and since did't find any where in the Google till now :(.

Comment: I had same problem in the past, I tried various approaches to get what I wanted. One way to do it is put your header content on the main content part of the report and then set expression there to make it hide depending on the pagenumber so it will not render that way on first page and it will be like header on other pages. It will give you what you want.